# Visual Studio: how to show a Migration Report?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

When I add a project file to my solution, an error popup writes:

> Operation could not be completed.  The project file cannot be
>   migrated. See the migration report for details.

How do I view the migration report?

(I'm trying to add dependencies to a project from GitHub.)

Comment: I'm also trying to figure this out

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2019, search for "UpgradeLog.htm" which is created in the project folder when you add project or solution files from previous versions of Visual Studio